# Is there a Bukkit Plugin that allows giving new users books?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit, server-administration, minecraft-java-edition-server

I was thinking, with the books Minecraft has come out with, it's time to replace those 500 blocks worth of signs with a simple book. Is there a Bukkit Plugin that will automatically give new users a rulebook?

Comment: They do it in MineZ so there's gotta be something which makes it possible.

Comment: @shanodin Assuming they use bukkit and not e.g. a custom server. But anyway, yes, [it is possible](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/123079/88)

Comment: @Zommuter true indeed

Comment: Are you willing to use command blocks instead, because you could do it that way?

Answer (score 3):

The [BookRules](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/bookrules/) plugin might be exactly what you are looking for:

> Automatically give players written books containing rules, getting started guides, etc when they join your server.

It's pretty simple to use:

- in the config file set `Seconds-Delay` to a value you deem appropriate. (It's the time in seconds between a new player login and the book being given to the player)
- In game, write a book with all the rules
- use `/rulebook add` to add the book as a rule book.
- enjoy

A plugin that would be nice would be a book read plugin keeping all new player in prison as long as they haven't finished reading the rule book.

Comment: +1, but re your last paragraph, that's just like EULA: everyone will click "read & understood", but once you're forced to do so you won't...

Answer (score 1):

You can use the tools referred to in the answer to my question [Is there a bukkit plugin to run small scripts when players (re)spawn?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/52798/is-there-a-bukkit-plugin-to-run-small-scripts-when-players-respawn), namely [Autorun command's](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/click-command/)

[`/addfirstjoincommand <identifier>`](http://dev.bukkit.org/bukkit-plugins/click-command/pages/commands/).