# How to use a command block to welcome new players on a server in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-java-edition-server

Ok, so me and my friend own a server, it uses Minecraft 1.6.4. What I can't seem to figure out, is how to welcome new users to the server by saying `Welcome USER To Northwood`, when they join.

Comment: If you're running a Bukkit server, you don't need to use command blocks, you just need some plugins: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/52798/1351

Comment: @MBraedley It's a FTB Monster server with a few extra mods

Comment: Okay, in that case I think it's still possible with scoreboards, but I'd have to test to make sure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you have them spawn 3 blocks above a hidden command block (powered with a simple clock), you could have that command block do something along the lines of **/testfor @p ~0 ~0 ~3** keep in mind that i'm not entirely certain if that's the specific thing to test for to check for players... then hook up a comparator from the first command block to a second one running the message command to @p ~0 ~3 ~3 or ~3 ~0 ~3 depending on which direction the comparator faces (and negative alterations would also be used as necessary)

Answer (score 1):

My best way to check first login independent on spawn position:

SIMPLE (one title):

1. /scoreboard teams add notFirstLogin
2. build simple clock f.e. 1 sec cyclus with block /testfor @a[team=]
3. result from testfor comparator goes to the welcome message (/title @a[team=]
4. after message put repeater with some delay and then command_block with:
   /scoreboard teams join notFirstLogin @a[team=]

logic of this proccess:

- player without team is first time on the server
- all players have some team except new guys
- if you have more complicated welcome (more than one title @a[team=] title ...) is necessary put there some waiting values:

COMPLICATED (more titles)

1. /scoreboard teams add notFirstLogin

   /scoreboard objectives add W8ing4Welcome dummy

   /scoreboard objectives add ShowWelcome dummy
2. build simple clock f.e. 1 sec cyclus with two cmd_blocks:
3. /scoreboard players set W8ing4Welcome @a[team=] 1

   ```
   3.x: ... others things that are necessary call at first login

   3.before_end: 
       small repeater delay 

   3.end:
       /scoreboard teams join notFirstLogin @a[team=]
   ```
4. /testfor @a[score_W8ing4Welcome_min=1] ... here connect all welcomes in series:

   ```
   4.1. logical circuit AND within /testfor @a[score_ShowWelcome_min=1] 
   ... checking that here is NOBODY with ShowWelcome=1 ... this is important to prevent covering of messages
   4.2. /scoreboard playes set @a[score_W8ing4Welcome_min=1] ShowWelcome 1
   4.3.  small repeater delay
   4.4. /scoreboard playes set  @a[score_ShowWelcome_min=1] W8ing4Welcome 0
   4.5.  small repeater delay
   4.6. /title @a[score_ShowWelcome_min=1] title ...
   4.7.  small repeater delay
   4.8. /title @a[score_ShowWelcome_min=1] title ...
   4.x  ....
   4.end. /scoreboard playes set @a[score_ShowWelcome_min=1] ShowWelcome 0
   ```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to test for new players use Johan37251's Command block creation way easier

https://pastebin.com/mHvJi41g