# Testfor blank scores Minecraft

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I need a tag or some sort of redstone method to scan for BLANK player scores; scores that haven't even been set to 0. Something like:

> /testfor @a[score_null=blank]

The problem is that all scores used to be automagically set to 0, but now player values must be "set/added/removed" to be detected.

Comment: As far as I'm aware, this is not possible. What is the end goal behind testing for a player without a particular score? Perhaps there's a workaround that could work here.

Comment: @Unionhawk I posted a possible workaround in the answers...

Comment: @Unionhawk Think it'll work for his purposes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding 0 to the player's score is the normal (and best AFAIK, in terms of lag and efficiency) way to do this.

`/testfor` and comparators is a lot more likely to break in circumstances such as two players logging in at the same time, or have issues with chunk loading. Plus you can't reliably do anything with the newly logged on player (can't welcome them, or give them items, or teleport them to spawn, etc.) if you're wanting to do that.

First, turn off `logAdminCommands` and `commandBlockOutput`, which should solve the problems you expressed with this method:

```
/gamerule logAdminCommands false
/gamerule commandBlockOutput false
```

Then, add 0 to everyone's score:

```
/scoreboard players add @a null 0
```

And then do whatever you want with with people who have 0 score by using this selector

```
@a[score_null=0,score_null_min=0]`
```

---

Another solution that answers your question without constantly adding to player's scores would be do test for the person having a score that is not blank, which can be easily done with this selector:

```
@a[score_null_min=-2147483648]
```

And then invert that to get all players that have a blank score.

---

The initial question is a bit of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), in that you're asking about your solution you've half worked out but got stuck on, rather than asking about the actual problem. Answers for how to detect new players (fairly common problem) can be found on [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/170388/how-to-use-a-command-block-to-welcome-new-players-on-a-server-in-minecraft).