# Detect when a player respawns, Possible?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have tried and tried but I can't find any solution that fits 1.13. Is there anyway possible to detect when a player respawns. My goal is to remove all the effects on a player when they respawns. But I'm just too bad. I have tried some commands from videos but they are just to outdated

I have tried [THIS](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8Hxp0gpYhLA) Video and it uses an old trick so it was no use. I tried to find a player respawn scoreboard with no luck. And finally I tried this:

(In a repeating command block, always acitve)

/execute as @a[scores={M_Death=1}] run effect clear @a[scores={M_Death=1}]

(In a chain command block, condential, always active)

/scoreboard players reset @a[scores={M_Death=1}] M_Death

Any idea anyone?

Comment: If you've made some attempts, it's a good idea to show us what you've tried.  Otherwise, answerers don't know that, and might be repeating what you've already done.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to delay command blocks until player respawns?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/354731/how-to-delay-command-blocks-until-player-respawns)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you have a scoreboard that tracks deaths, you only need to find players that are alive and have a score of 1 or more on that scoreboard. The `@a` target selector targets all players, regardless of whether they are alive or dead. The `@e[type=player]` target selector only targets alive players. This is the result:

```
/effect clear @e[type=player,scores={deaths=1..}]
/scoreboard players reset @e[type=player,scores={deaths=1..}] deaths
```